# CocoaPods products not building

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

I am attempting to use CocoaPods in a project, but am having difficulty getting the pods to build.

[image: The POD "Products" do not build.]

Setup seemed to work as expected. The "pod install" succeeds.

[image: pod install succeeds]

Searching the file system for libPods.a yields no results so I don't think it's merely a path problem.

I also ran pod --verbose install. There weren't any errors there.

Comment: Did you compile the pods project? or build your entire workspace. the `libPods.a` will be build when you build your project since it is depended on it.

Comment: I open the workspace and press build. The workspace shows both the pods project and my app's project. Possibly the build button is only building my project and not the Pods project. I tried opening the Pods project separately and the build button is grayed out.

Comment: Well in my project the all the products in the pods project are read as well. But when I build my project the library is build and linked to my project. So what seems to be your problem exectly ?

Comment: How can I distinguish in XCode between building the App Project only and building everything in the workspace? I assumed that if you opened the workspace and pressed -build- that everything should be built.

Comment: And you assumed correctly, when using cocoapods you should always open the workspace. Opening the project will just fail to build.

Comment: I'm not sure what to check next. I open the workspace. I press build. There are no errors - everything seems to work except the static libraries in Pods -> Products don't exist at the end of the process.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46856/discussion-between-bbrame-and-rckoenes)

Comment: Having the products in red is normal unless you compile in release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though they are red your workspace is being build and builds the `libPod.a` in the `/temp`.